# SVG function for rollover and rollout

Tags: javascript, svg

I am playing around with SVG and in rollOver function, I Dynamically created a SVG text and a link to website. When the mouse is over the "Hello World", the text change to "Click to go to SVGOpen" with a link. Then the rollOut function called when the mouse is out of text. The "Click to go to SVGOpen" is change back to "Hello World". The problem is that when I rollover, the "Hello World" does not disappear and the "Click to go to SVGOpen" overlap it. Then when I rollout, the "CLick to go to SVGOpen" does not disappear. What am I missing? Here my sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="100%" height="100%" onload="init();">

 <script type="text/javascript">
 <![CDATA[
    var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
    var svgns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";



        function init(){
            var image=document.createElementNS(svgns, 'image');
            image.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '75px');
            image.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '125px');
            image.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '200px');
            image.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '850px');
            image.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'xlink:href', 'svgOpen.png');

            document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(image);
        }

        /* 
        All in this part must happen/be assigned when the document is loaded:
        create an image element that has
            -a x value of 75px
            -a y value of 125px
            -a height of 200px
            -a width of 850px
            -shows the svgOpen.png

        Alter the title text you created in part 1 below so that:
            -is embedded inside of an 'a' tag (dynamically created <a> of course!)
            -when the title text is clicked, the <a> takes you to http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/ 
                    (using the <a> tag - do NOT try to go to the other page via JavaScript)
            -when the title is moused over the text changes to "Click to go to SVGOpen"
            -when the title is moused out the text changes back to "Your Names Practice"

    */

        function rollOver(){

            link=document.createElementNS(svgns, 'a');
            link.setAttributeNS(null,'target','_blank');
            link.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'xlink:href', 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/');

            var tEle=document.createElementNS(svgns,'text');
            tEle.setAttributeNS(null,'id','clicky');
            tEle.setAttributeNS(null,'x','150px');
            tEle.setAttributeNS(null,'y','75px');
            tEle.setAttributeNS(null,'fill','#999966');
            tEle.setAttributeNS(null,'font-size','48px');

            link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click to go to SVGOpen'));
            tEle.appendChild(link);

            document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(tEle);


        }
        function rollOut()
        {

            var tEle=document.createElementNS(svgns,'rollOver()');

            link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'));
            tEle.appendChild(link);
            document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(tEle);
        }   
    /*
        Extra Fun:  (be sure you are done with all else before you try this!)
            When I click on the dynamically created image above, dynamically create an ellipse
            that animates...
            ellipse: cx random value between 0 and 100%
                     cy random value between 0 and 100%
                     rx random value between 50 and 140
                     ry random value between 30 and 40
                     stroke width random value between 1 and 8
                     fill #ccffff
                     stroke #663399
            animate: 1 to 0 opacity
                     duration random value between 1 and 6
                     when 0 is reached, remove the ellipse
                     animate begins on the creation

    */
    /*
        function imageClick()
        {
            var ellipse = document.createElementNS(svgns, "ellipse");
            ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"cx","Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)";
            ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"cy","Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)";
            ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"rx","Math.floor(Math.random() * 91) + 50";
            ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"ry","Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 30";
            ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#ccffff");
            ellipse.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke","#663399");

            a.appendChild(ellipse);
            document.documentElement.appendChild(a);

        }
    */
    ]]>
 </script>


    <!-- 1) Everything below here is to be created as tags, NOT dynamically created...
    create a background that covers the WHOLE page (no matter how big) that is 
    #333366 -->
    <g>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: #333366; stroke: none;" />>       
    </g>

    <!-- create a title with your name's practical! - like (B's Practice!)
    at x of 150px, y of 75px, the color (#999966) and font size (48px)--> 

    <a>
        <text x="150px" y="75px" fill="#999966" font-size="48px" onmouseover="rollOver();" onmouseout="rollOut();">
            Hello World
        </text>
    </a>




    <!-- create a rect that has:
        x of 50px, y of 100px, width of 0, height of 0, fill of #ffffcc
        and rounded corners of 25px!

        Now, animate it so that the rect's
        -width grows to 80% over 2 seconds
        -height grows to 80% over 3 seconds
        -rotation rotates once around 1 second AFTER the height animate is done (MUST watch the 
        height's id to see when it is done, NOT by time).  It should take the rotation 1.5 seconds
        to complete

    -->
  <rect x="50px" y="100px" width="0px" height="0px" rx="25px" ry="25px" style="fill: #ffffcc; stroke: none;">
        <animateTransform attributeName="width" to="80%" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="height" to="80%" dur="3s" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="1.5s" begin="6s"/>
    </rect>


</svg>
```

Comment: Why are you using `type="text/javascript"`? Should you be using `type="application/ecmascript"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handlers, you are simply appending an element to your document (`appendChild`). So what you're describing isn't surprising, you're not doing anything to remove the previous element, so it's still displayed. You also keep adding, so your document grows and grows as you move your mouse in and out.

You could solve this by removing the other element (get the element and call method `removeChild`) in each event handler.

But alternatively, instead of adding/removing elements whenever a mouse event occurs, a simpler approach would be to include both versions in the document and use CSS styling to show/hide them depending on the hover state.

Comment: I got rollOut() function work by using document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].removeChild(ele); to remove "Click to go to SVGOpen" text. However, on rollOver() function, I couldn't figure out how to hide Hello World SVG text to avoid other text overlap. I tried removeChild(); it does remove it but the "rollover" text doesn't show up because Hello World text is actually remove, not hidden.